# Why is $\langle y,x\rangle +\langle x,y\rangle=2\Re \langle x,y\rangle$?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I wonder about the second step of the proof shown below (d) in the picture attached. Why is  $\langle y,x\rangle +\langle x,y\rangle=2\Re \langle x,y\rangle$?

[image: scan of a textbook]

Answer (score 5):

For a [hermitian inner product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermitianInnerProduct.html) we have
$$\langle y,x\rangle=\overline{\langle x,y\rangle}$$
so

$$\langle y,x\rangle+\langle x,y\rangle=\overline{\langle x,y\rangle}+\langle x,y\rangle=2\operatorname{Re}\langle x,y\rangle$$